# Table view cell, custom editor and editing frame

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nstableviewcell

I am using a custom editor when editing the contents of a cell inside a Table view. From the docs I see that the custom editor has to be an NSTextView. So I put the text view in the document view, then I referenced it from the cell subclass through an IBOutlet in order to assign it as custom editor.

When doing all this, I can set the editor not to draw its background, but a thick white border is shown when the user edits that cell, and there is no way to remove it.

So I create the NSTextView programmatically, assigned it as the custom editor, and no white border is shown, *but* I can't change the background now, set it to clearColor, set the font, fontColor etc. I can't do anything with it. It is just a square with dark background and white text.

Is there something I am not doing? This is a bad approach?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The border is drawn by drawRect:, but I still don't know how to fix it by overriding drawRect:...

You may have a look at this link: http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/129091-solved-re-disabling-nstableview-big-black-editing-box.html#129259